# can not POST to website and hitting search

Tags: python, html, request

I am trying to make a post request to that website:  http://archive.eso.org/wdb/wdb/asm/dimm_paranal/form

so far I did that:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'http://archive.eso.org/wdb/wdb/asm/dimm_paranal/form'
p = {'search': 'Search',
     'start_date' : '2019-09-17..2019-09-18'}

post = requests.post(url,data=p)
```

when I analyse the text from the post I only get the form webpage html code and not the result of the query. How can I simulate the query?

Additional question: How can I check the checkboxes in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form has an action, in this case it is `/wdb/wdb/asm/dimm_paranal/query`. Try to send the request there...

In devtools (Ctrl+Shift+I) you have "Network". Go there and see what is actually requested, check all the data, response, headers and so on.

Another help I would recommend is a programm caled Postman. You can create requests there, no need to code it.

Additional answer to your additional question: The checkboxes have no default value. Just set anything. `1`, `true`, whatever. It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made me go in the right direction!